# In Xcode 11.4, I Cannot Hide A Button

Tags: swift, xcode

So I am trying to make an  Painting app that can store the data that user gives (such as name of the painting, artist of the painting, year of the painting and image of the painting) and shows in a table view. I have 2 view controllers, first one is called `ViewController` that has a table view for showing the data (only name of the painting for the table view cell) and the second one is called `DetailedVC` which is for entering and saving the data, also showing the details of the data. In the second view controller I added 3 text fields, 1 image view that enables the user to go the photo library and a save button. I wrote this in my `DetailedVC` script for when the user taps one of the elements from the table view in my `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if chosenPainting != "" {

            savebutton.isHidden = true //Trying to hide the save button here!!

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Paintings")
            let idString = chosenPaintingId?.uuidString
            fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", idString!)
            fetch.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(fetch)
                if results.count > 0 {
                    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                        if let name = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String {
                            nameText.text = name
                        }
                        if let artist = result.value(forKey: "artist") as? String {
                            artistText.text = artist
                        }
                        if let year = result.value(forKey: "year") as? Int {
                            yearText.text = String(year)
                        }
                        if let imageData = result.value(forKey: "image") as? Data {
                            let imageD = UIImage(data: imageData)
                            imageView.image = imageD
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        } else {
            savebutton.isEnabled = false
            nameText.text = ""
            artistText.text = ""
            yearText.text = ""
        }
```

I get the information from my `ViewController` like this:

```
    @objc func AddButtonTapped(){
        selectedPainting = ""
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailedVC", sender: self)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedPaintingId = ids[indexPath.row]
        selectedPainting = names[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailedVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toDetailedVC" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! DetailedVC
            destination.chosenPainting = selectedPainting
            destination.chosenPaintingId = selectedPaintingId
        }
    }
```

It works just fine below the `savebutton.isHidden = true`. I don't understand why the button is not disappearing. Everything else works correctly, text field's texts turn into the information that user gave but, the button is standing still right in the bottom. And even  the `savebutton.isEnabled = false` is working. I thought there must be a problem with connection between my script and my storyboard so I deleted and did it again, but it didn't work again. I must have doing something wrong, can you help me about this?

Comment: You may have multiple buttons with the same name. And viewDidLoad will only run once, so check what it sets when it is executed.

Comment: @gnasher729 I only have one button and I have looked at the source code of the storyboard too for checking if there is a connection, everything looks fine and actually everything works fine too. I added some `print` statements too to see what is happening and I saw everything works fine. But still the button does not disappear :( Do you think that it might be a bug? I am starting to think that way.